# Backbone json to models

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have the following json string and I am trying to create a model from each name/value pair. I have a attr in each model called "name"

```
"[{"name":"A01"},{"name":"A02"},{"name":"A03"},{"name":"A04"},{"name":"A05"},{"name":"A06"},{"name":"A07"},{"name":"A08"},{"name":"A09"},{"name":"A10"},{"name":"A11"},{"name":"A12"},{"name":"A13"},{"name":"A14"},{"name":"A15"},{"name":"A16"},{"name":"B01"},{"name":"B02"},{"name":"B03"},{"name":"B04"},{"name":"B05"},{"name":"B06"},{"name":"B07"},{"name":"B08"},{"name":"B09"},{"name":"B10"},{"name":"B11"},{"name":"B12"},{"name":"B13"},{"name":"B14"},{"name":"B15"},{"name":"B16"},{"name":"C01"},{"name":"C02"},{"name":"C03"},{"name":"C04"},{"name":"C05"},{"name":"C06"},{"name":"C07"},{"name":"C08"},{"name":"C09"},{"name":"C10"},{"name":"C11"},{"name":"C12"},{"name":"C13"},{"name":"C14"},{"name":"C15"},{"name":"C16"},{"name":"D01"},{"name":"D02"},{"name":"D03"},{"name":"D04"},{"name":"D05"},{"name":"D06"},{"name":"D07"},{"name":"D08"},{"name":"D09"},{"name":"D10"},{"name":"D11"},{"name":"D12"},{"name":"D13"},{"name":"D14"},{"name":"D15"},{"name":"D16"}]"
```

This is my code where Teams is a collection of team. I am getting a new model for each character.

```
var myteams = new Teams( _.map(data, function(p) { return p.name } ));
var app = app || {};
var Teams = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Team,
    initialize: function (models,options) { }
});

var app = app || {};

app.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name: ''
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('This is ' +typeof(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: Add the code of `Teams` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks like `data` is probably a raw JSON string, not an actual array of objects. Have you properly converted that with `JSON.parse` already?

Secondly, you are passing an array of strings to the `Teams` collection constructor. Don't do that. You must pass an array of objects, so forget your `_.map` call, just make sure `data` is an array of objects and pass that directly to your `Teams` constructor.

Third, FYI once you get your Teams collection properly populated, use `myteams.pluck("name")` if you want a list of each team's name. (Just FYI on this one).